# Parse lines with specific pattern out of file

Tags: command-line, bash, perl

I have a file that looks roughly like this :

```
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993 ((758:0.000598847,726:0.000598847)
position:
sites: 5 4 2 1 3 4 543 5  67 657  78 67 8  5645 6 
01010010101010101010101010101011111100011
1111010010010101010101010111101000100000
00000000000000011001100101010010101011111
```

Now I would like to extract only those lines which start with [numeric]: from the file. It is not always only the first two, it could also be the first 7 or 8 or whatever. How would I read in this file and output a file only containing the lines with [numeric]:?

Comment: Please don't damage posts.

Comment: this shoudl eb deleted

Comment: No. It. Shouldn't. What is wrong with it? Do not attempt to remove valid posts, it's vandalism. It's also spelt "This should be deleted".

Answer (score 9):

Using `grep` :

```bsh
$ grep "^\[[0-9]\+\]:" file.txt 
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993 ((758:0.000598847,726:0.000598847)
```

To save the output in a file (`output.txt`):

```
grep "^\[[0-9]\+\]:" file.txt > output.txt
```

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
  print '\n'.join([line.rstrip() for line in f if re.search(r'^\[\d+\]:', line)])
```

Answer (score 5):

The `perl` way:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^(\[[0-9]*\]:.*)/' testdata > out
```

The `awk` way:

```
awk 'match($0, /^\[[0-9]*\]:/)' testdata > out
```

---

*Output for both commands*

```
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993 ((758:0.000598847,726:0.000598847)
```

Answer (score 2):

This task is perfectly suited for [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/grep.1.html), because you're just checking which lines contain a match for a pattern and printing the lines that do.

[heemayl's way](https://askubuntu.com/a/621238/22949) is excellent. Here's another that's similar but uses [Perl regular expression syntax](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/perlre.1.html) (which GNU grep supports, with `-P`), for a shorter and slightly simpler pattern:

```bash
grep -P '\[\d+\]:' infile
```

That just prints the output, but you can redirect it to *`outfile`*:

```
grep -P '\[\d+\]:' infile > outfile
```

In Perl regular expressions, `\d` matches any single digit, same as `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

---

In case you're interested, here's a [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sed.1.html) way:

```bash
sed -nr '/^\[[0-9]+\]:/p' infile
```

```bash
sed -nr '/^\[[0-9]+\]:/p' infile > outfile
```

That checks each line to see if it matches `^\[[0-9]+\]:`. If it does, the sed command `p` is used to print the line. The `-n` flag prevents any lines from being printed except as provided for explicitly by the `sed` script.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no posibility of a `[non-numeric]` at the beginning of your file lines, then simply `grep -E '^\['` will do the trick, viz.:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.tmp
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993 ((758:0.000598847,726:0.000598847)
position:
sites: 5 4 2 1 3 4 543 5  67 657  78 67 8  5645 6
01010010101010101010101010101011111100011
1111010010010101010101010111101000100000
00000000000000011001100101010010101011111

$ grep -E '^\[' /tmp/tmp.tmp
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993 ((758:0.000598847,726:0.000598847)

$
```

Comment: In addition to `[non-numeric]` (as you say), this will also print lines containing *only* `[`, or starting with `[` with no matching `]` to close it or no `:` afterwards. (That might or might not be considered desirable.)

Comment: @Eliah, as user3069326 knows the structure of the input file, he's in a good position to ascertain if my suggestion is valid.